# Calculate $\int_{[0,1]}xdm$ by Lebesgue integral definition of positive functions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Calculate $\int_{[0,1]}xdm$ by Lebesgue integral definition of positive functions

---

Consider the sequence of simple functions $$\phi_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\mathcal{X}_{[\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\frac{1}{2^{k}}]}$$

$0\leq\phi_n\leq f$ and $$\int_{[0,1]}\phi_ndm=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n\mathcal{X}_{[0,1]}dm=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}{(\frac{1}{2^{k}}-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}})}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}}$$

so $\phi_n \in L^1 $
and by definition $\int_{[0,1]}xdm=\sup \bigg\{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_ndm: 0\leq\phi_n\leq f \:\text{and} \:  \phi_n \in L^1\bigg\}\geq \lim_n \int_{[0,1]}\phi_ndm=\lim_n \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}}=1/2$

And we have shown $\int_{[0,1]}xdm\ge1/2$

**how can I show the inverse inequality ?**

Comment: Have you tried considering a sequence of simple functions that are slightly above the identity?

Comment: @MushuNrek Yes, but I can't find the right one. For example $\mathcal{X}_{[0,1]}$ is above the identity, but the integral doesn't equal to $1/2$

Comment: try $\psi_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \chi_{[2^{-(k+1)}, 2^{-k}]}$

Comment: @MushuNrek thank you! I was stuck for a long time.